La sombra del modal aparece mal
Tengo un modal de login que quiero que aparezca en el centro de la pantalla, y que la sombra quede detras en toda la pantalla obviamente.
Pero de momento me queda asi:

Tengo el modal en la misma pagina html:


.modal {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.modal-content {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
<div id="loginModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <h2>Inicio de Sesión</h2>
    <form action="login/login.php" method="post">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="input-container">
          <label for="username">Usuario:</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Usuario">
        </div>
        
        <div class="input-container">
          <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
        </div>

      </div>
      <button type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</button>
      <button type="submit">Registrarse</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>



De qué manera se puede hacer que el cuadro de inicio de sesión que se ve en la imagen aparezca centrado, y que la sombra quede en todo el resto de la pantalla?
Además, me gustaria tirar los botones a la derecha.

Para lograr que el backdrop ocupe toda la pantalla y que los botones queden alineados a la derecha, debes aplicar los estilos que te sugiero a continuación:


function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("loginModal").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("backdrop").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("loginModal").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("backdrop").style.display = "none";
}
.modal {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.modal-content {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Alineamos los botones a la derecha */

.close,
.modal-content button {
  float: right;
}

/* Agregamos el CSS para el backdrop */

.backdrop {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 1;
}
<button onclick="openModal()">Abrir Modal</button>

<div id="loginModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <h2>Inicio de Sesión</h2>
    <form action="login/login.php" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-container">
          <label for="username">Usuario:</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Usuario">
        </div>
        <div class="input-container">
          <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</button>
      <button type="submit">Registrarse</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="backdrop" class="backdrop" onclick="closeModal()"></div>



Debes ajustar este ejemplo al código de tu proyecto ya que no compartiste todo el código necesario para lanzar el modal y el div que genera el backdrop, por mencionar algo.

Hola, muchisimas gracias, funciono perfecto.

Es con todo el gusto. Recuerda darle un voto positivo a la respuesta para que sea de utilidad a futuros visitantes y de paso ambos ganamos reputación en la comunidad.
